# How to tell .pcapng file frame amount before fully open it?

Tags: networking, wireshark, packet, tshark

I get huge .cap files by iptrace on AIX. The file is about 800MB. I'm on MacOS, and tshark has been running for a whole day parsing it.

CPU of my host keeps 99% occupied. I really need to speed it up.

I've already added -n flag of tshark.

I'm thinking about adding frame number range to the filter, which should narrow down the amount of packets for analysis. But I don't know the total amount of frames, therefore can't really add that parameter.

1. Can I browse some general info about the .cap file before fully open it?
2. Is there anything else to do to remarkably speed up tshark performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps TShark is stuck in an infinite loop, in which case the problem isn't "the file is too big" (I have a capture that's 776MB, and it takes only a few minutes to run it through `tshark -V`, albeit on a 2.8 GHz Core i7 MBP with 16GB of main memory), the problem is "TShark/Wireshark have a bug".

File a bug on [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org/), specifying the TShark command that's been running for a day (all command-line arguments).  You may have to either provide the capture file for testing by the Wireshark developers or run test versions of TShark.